# Calling textbox information from one form to another

Tags: c#, datatable

I have 2 forms: The first form has textboxes that display different task names and times spent on each task. The second form has a `datagridView`. Using:

```
        public void DataTableTest()
    {
        //Create DataTable 
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //Add Columns
        dt.Columns.Add("Task Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Time Worke (HH:mm:ss)", typeof(string));
        //Add Rows
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

I am able to get the data table layout the way I want. My issue is, I want to pull the `textbox.text` from `Form1` to populate the `[0][0]` cell of the data table. Something like:

```
        //Add Rows
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[0][0] = Form1.tasktextbox1.text;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

But this is not working. I am getting the following from my error list when I try to start the program:

> 'TaskTracker.Form1.TaskTextBox1' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Thank you in advance for the assistance. If you have any questions ask, first time posting and new to programming.

Comment: Your error may be caused by the form being a `private` class, most likely. Please make sure it's a `public` (partial) class.

Comment: Quick suggestion, it may be better to make a property to get the string in the `tasktextbox` instead of going to the `TextBox` in the form directly, it may make maintenance easier in the long run because `Form1` will be the only thing responsible for the `TextBox` and all of the other classes will just be interested in the data, not how it's shown to users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error describes itself: `TaskTextBox1` is a private member of `Form1` and you cannot call it on another class. Add a property to `Form1`:

```
Public string task1text { get { return this.textbox1.text; }}
```

and then use it on the other form:

```
dt.Rows[0][0] = Form1.task1text;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! VS will start the program, but after entering some text in TaskTextBox1 and launching the second form (the datatable populates on load), the text is not populating. However, if I mainly assign text from Properties, it loads the data table with the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to complete this task with:

```
    public static string task1text;

    public void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        task1text = TaskTextBox1.Text;
        ReportForm RF = new ReportForm();
        RF.Show();
    }
```

on form1 and using Roozbeh's suggestion on the second form:

```
    dt.Rows[0][0] = Form1.task1text;
```

Thank you all for your assistance. Slowly figuring it out! :)